# Limit overpy query to specific area (e.g. country)

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

In the following code I am defining the spatial extent of the query using a bounding box. How could I modify the code to instead use a country as the extent of my query? Thank you.

```
api = overpy.Overpass()
result = api.query("""<osm-script>
  <query type="node">
    <has-kv k="crossing" v="zebra"/>
    <bbox-query e="6.608804" n="53.417560" s="51.967099" w="4.655094"/>
  </query>
  <print/>
</osm-script>""")
len(result.nodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

In overpass turbo a count of the zebra crossings in Ireland:

```
[out:json];
area["name"="Ireland"]->.boundaryarea;
(
  nwr(area.boundaryarea)[crossing=zebra];
);

out body;
```

And with overpy a count of the zebra crossings in Ireland:

```
import overpy

api = overpy.Overpass()

result = api.query("""
    area["name"="Ireland"]->.boundaryarea;
    (
    nwr(area.boundaryarea)[crossing=zebra];
    );

    out body;
    """)
print(len(result.nodes))
```